Analog Magazine short story from about 1972 or '73 about a Russian/Soviet occupation of Eastern Canada and Northern Maine after a war

Analog Magazine.
Russian Soviet occupation of Canada and Northern Maine.
Early 1970's.


Do you remember anything else about the story?

Somewhat similar to Christopher Anvil's "Ideological Defeat" in Analog, September 1972.

Possibly A Sleep and a Forgetting by Orson Scott Card?
It was published in 1979 not the early 70s, and it was published as part of the "Analog book" called Capitol not as a standalone short story, but the plot broadly matches i.e. the Russians do invade Canada then Northern Maine.

From the story:

Instead the senator handed him a short press release. "Go ahead and read it. The President's reading it to the press right now." It said:
"Today Russian troops entered New York State and Maine from Quebec. The National Guard is trying to cope with the emergency as U.S. Army units converge on the area. We believe that the aggression will be dealt with shortly, but in, the meantime we are proceeding with an orderly evacuapon of New York City, Buffalo, Rochester, and other major cities that seem to be primary targets for the enemy.
"Throughout our administration we have struggled to maintain at least a semblance of detente. We have struggled for peace. Let the court of world opinion decide whether we have done badly. But the time for peace and restraint has ended. We will fight as necessary to preserve our great nation.
"Because I know it will be asked, I answer the question, 'Will we use nuclear weapons?' The answer is an unequivocal no. I wish I could say the reason was altruistic. But blood will be shed anyway. The reason we will not launch our missiles is because today our aerial photographs showed that the Russians did not remove their missiles from Quebec or Cuba after all. Today they removed the camouflage so we would know how futile an attempt to launch missiles would be. Because the moment we begin preparations for launch; the enemy will have destroyed us. It is that simple. So we will fight on the ground and in the air and on the sea with conventional weapons, and, God willing, we shall prevail. Pray for our soldiers. And pray for their commanders."

